# Unable to make push function for linked-list

Tags: c, linked-list

After many hours of searching in **`google`** and **`stackoverflow`**, finally I couldn't release an obvious way to make **`push`** function for **`linked-list`**.

I wanna make **`push`** function which adds new **`node`** with new **`value`** at the end of a particular **`linked-list`**. My last effort to do this is shown below but it doesn't work.

Where I made mistake and how I can fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node_t;

void push(node_t *h, int val){

    //copy value head
    node_t *copy;
    copy = h;

    //reach to last node
    while(copy->next != NULL)
        copy = h->next;

    //make new node and value "val"
    copy->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    copy->next->next = NULL;
    copy->next->value = val;
}

int main(){

    node_t h;

    h.next = NULL;
    push(&h, 100);
    push(&h, 200);
    push(&h, 300);

    printf("%d", h.next->value);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Additional information:
It was compiled properly but it wasn't ran.
I use **`TDM-GCC`** and **`C`** language not **`C++`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop is wrong,

```
    //reach to last node
    while(copy->next != NULL)
        copy = h->next;
```

You are assigning `h->next` again and again. It will be an infinite loop when `h->next` is not `NULL` and `h->next->next` is not `NULL`.

The loop should be:

```
    //reach to last node
    while(copy->next != NULL)
        copy = copy->next;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my program still doesn't work!

Comment: @PoyalPaxicam [It works.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/02OV34Tx18BWY9Ya) It successfully prints the value in the first node.

Comment: For me it prints nothing!

Comment: @PoyalPaxicam Check if you are compiling and running the intended newest code.